# How to get a report of all mac addresses on another subnet?

Tags: snmp, subnet, mac-address, mpls

We have an MPLS consisting of two branches: Location1 and Location2.

I am using the Softperfect netscan to report all ip addresses and mac addresses of devices on Location1 where my workstation is located (subnet1).

However, I want to have the same report on my workstation (at location1) for all devices in Location2 which is on a separate subnet which I administer.

Now I know I could get that report via remote-desktop connection to a machine there and running netscan.

How can I get the report directly?

I would like a similar report:

- All connected devices
- device name
- ip addresses
- mac addresses

Somebody told me about using SNMP?

Comment: How are they linked together? Can you reach any of the devices in location 2? It's a matter of being able to *reach* the other network...

Comment: SNMP on your remote switch MIGHT give you the Address Table, but you'd have to query the SNMP interface and look for the OID that houses the Address Table.  But, that depends entirely on the hardware you have.  The web interfaces on most SOHO switches show it somewhere typically too.

Comment: @NathanC - they are connected together as an MPLS (I think I did mention that, actually).  That means any device can ping any other device from either subnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We went about setting up our MPLS in a different manner.  Now when I run the netscan, it does indeed, give me a report of the MAC addresses of devices on the other subnet.

In an MPLS, if properly configured, the two subnets should work together as if they were a single network - file-sharing works normally, computers can discover each other on the other subnet, etc.

I am using the SoftPerfect Network Scanner, and enter the range of my other subnet, and it is ppulated normally.

I think the solution also has to do with having a working WINS server established.

Answer (score 4):

You can't (unless you have two subnets on the same network segment).  You have to do this via a machine (or the router) in the Location2 network. Because broadcasts don't cross router boundries.

Comment: What do you mean by "same network segment"?

Comment: Well technically I mean a 'Broadcast domain'. They usually correspond to subnets. In basic terms if there is a router physically between you and Location2 then that splits the network.

Comment: Is there a workaround?  If I am administrator on both subnets, surely there is a way to fetch the info - maybe via some application that gets installed in both subnets and talks to itself?

Comment: Yes of course, numerous ways, but that is really a whole new question

Comment: Is it really a different question? My question was: *How to get a report of all mac addresses on another subnet?* How would you ask the "different question"? (thanks for your help)

Comment: No, your question was *how can I get the report directly?*  So you need to ask what you can use to collect this info and forward it on which although points to the same aim has an entirely different focus.

Comment: Okay, I suppose you are right.  By "directly" I meant directly on my workstation without having to remote to the other network, but I see now that "directly" could be interpreted in other ways.  I'll think about another question and hope that since the aims are the same that it won't get closed.